# R data frame: columns by count

Tags: r

all,

I have a data frame with thousands of elements along the lines of

`rawdata <- data.frame("Pop" = c("A","B","B","C","C") , "ID" = c(1,2,2,1,1))`

| Pop | ID |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 1 |

and am trying to create an output like

| ID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |

But I'm struggling to figure how to do this.
Would anyone happen to know a way?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try `xtabs(~ID + Pop, rawdata)`

Answer (score 2):

We can create counts of occurrences following a `group_by` to `summarise` procedure, or use the `dplyr` function `count` directly as a shortcut. To then transform the data into a wide shape, `pivot_wider` can be used. Here the values are taken from the column `n`, the default column name that is the reuslt of `count`. Lastly, `NA` values are to be transformed into zeros.

```
library(tidyverse)
rawdata %>%
  count(Pop, ID) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Pop, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
     ID     A     B     C
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     0     2
2     2     0     2     0
```